# Как в java с наиболее меньшим объемом кода сохранить только сами значения полей объекта в массив байт?

Tags: java

Имеется объект с большим количество полей типа байт и массив байт, как можно с наиболее меньшим объемом кода сохранить только сами значения полей объекта в массив байт? наподобие как это например делается на с++: char* pBuffer = (char*)&some_object;

используя сериализацию помимо самих значений полей записываются также метаданные, что меня не устраивает

объект логически представляет собой структуру(как в c++ структура), то есть данные, которые удобно заполнять обращаясь к полям. и мне нужно сохранять в массив байт только сами значений полей
пример объекта:

```
class AnyClass
{
    private byte field1=0;
    private byte field2=1;
    private byte[] field3={0,1,2,3};
    .
    .
    .
    private byte field40=40;
}
```

Comment: Скорость критична ?

Comment: нет не критична

Comment: Лучше в вопрос добавьте пример объекта, так желающим помочь станет проще пример показать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если скорость не имеет значения, в ход обычно пускают рефлексию, если скорость критична, используют сериализацию без рефлексии. Есть куча уроков как осуществить сереализацию через тот же класс java.io.Serializable.

### Сериализация без рефлексии.

Сам процесс такой сериализации можно собственноручно пощупать на примере 2 методов:

```
public interface IMySerialized {

    byte[] serialize(); // метод должен будет собрать у класса сериализованные данные
    void deserialize(byte[] data); // метод, который по сериализованным данным должен будет заполнить поля класса

}

public class Test implements IMySerialized {

    private byte a; // наши поля
    private byte b;

    public byte[] serialize() {
        return new byte[]{a,b}; // содержимое метода несёт чисто теоретический смысл
    }

    void deserialize(byte[] data) {
        this.a = data[0]; // содержимое метода несёт чисто теоретический смысл
        this.b = data[1];
    }

}
```

Суть такой безрефлексийной сериализации в том, что вы сами реализуете алгоритм сбора всей информации с полей в методе serialize, и сами реализуете обратный алгоритм разбора данных и заполнения полей в методе deserialize. То есть, добавляя новое поле, оба этих метода увеличивают свой объём.

### Сериализация с рефлексией.

Тут всё изощрённее. Обычно,  создаётся одна/две аннотации, которые дают нашему сериализатору понять что нужно сериализовать, а что можно пропускать. Обычно, проще считать что все поля являются сериализуемыми, поэтому, метки делают только ради исключений. Пример нашего тестового класса:

```
public class Test {

    private byte a;
    private byte b;

}
```

Далее, собирается обработчик-сериализатор. Суть обработчика - через рефлексию вытащить все поля, в случае необходимости, проверить их аннотации, и пропустить игнорируемые поля. Далее, собрать все данные полей в кучу.

```
public static <T> byte[] serialize(T obj) throws Exception {
    List<Byte> result = new ArrayList<Byte>();
    for(Field field : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) { // перебираем все поля в классе
        field.setAccessible(true); // если поле приватное, меняем доступ к нему
        Object data = field.get(obj); // читаем значение из поля
        if(data instanceof byte[]) {
            for(byte b : (byte[])data){
                result.add(b);
            }
            continue;
        }
        if(data instanceof Byte){
            result.add((Byte)data);
            continue;
        }
    }
    byte[] array = new byte[result.size()];
    for(int i = result.size()-1; i>=0; i--){
        array[i]=result.get(i);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Аналогичным образом пишется обратная обработка - десереализация.

Пример использования такого кода:

```
Test  test  = new Test();
Test2 test2 = new Test2();
byte[] data1 = MyHandler.serialise(test);
byte[] data2 = MyHandler.serialise(test2);
```

Причём, если сериализатор написан грамотно, то в дальнейшем, ему не важно что сериализовать, он одинаково легко разберёт любой класс и выпотрошит все его поля.

Comment: Исправил код, работает исключительно для вашего примера.